# How can I turn off MobGriefing but only on one item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-forge

So I was playing with my friends on a modded server and they wanted to steal some items from a dragon... This, of course, didn't get as planned because seemingly sleeping monster woke up and set everything on fire. One friend's stuff didn't burn because one mod - erebus - adds graves to the game but second player wasn't that lucky - dragon broke his tomb and all his items are gone now.

**And here is a question: how can I make graves indestructible for mobs but destructable for players?**

(basically turn off MobGriefing on this item only)

Informations you may need:

- Mod for dragons: Ice and Fire
- Mod for graves: erebus
- Grave id: erebus:block_of_bones
- Server software: Magma

Thanks in advance,
Jaro975